# yarn + webpack search path

Tags: npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I'm looking at a project which has a package.json file that contains the following line:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf lib && rm -rf umd",
    "prebuild": "yarn clean",
    "build": "../../node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
    "build-production": "yarn build && TS_NODE_PROJECT=\"tsconfig.webpack.json\" webpack",
    "watch": "../../node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -w",
    "test": "",
    "lint": "../../node_modules/.bin/tslint -c ../../tslint.json -p ./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
```

webpack is not in my path, so run webpack

```
$ webpack
-bash: /usr/bin/webpack: No such file or directory
```

Yet somehow when I run "yarn build-production" .. things seem to work as expected. In face you can see "Version: webpack 4.25.1" in the output.

```
yarn build-production
yarn run v1.13.0
$ yarn build && TS_NODE_PROJECT="tsconfig.webpack.json" webpack
$ yarn clean
$ rm -rf lib && rm -rf umd
$ ../../node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
Hash: 365eaed22ba7f6d609fc
Version: webpack 4.25.1
Time: 1289ms
Built at: 01/24/2019 5:03:35 PM
                              Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                  ../lib/index.d.ts  268 bytes          [emitted]
eos-transit-scatter-provider.min.js    4.3 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = eos-transit-scatter-provider.min.js
[0] ./src/index.ts 6.6 KiB {0} [built]
[1] external "ScatterJS" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[2] external "ScatterEOS" 42 bytes {0} [built]
Done in 8.04s.
```

What's confusing me is that I don't understand how the npm script is able to find the webpack binary and use it. When obviously if I run the same command in a shell it'll fail because webpack is not install in my search path.

```
$ yarn build && TS_NODE_PROJECT="tsconfig.webpack.json" webpack
yarn run v1.13.0
$ yarn clean
$ rm -rf lib && rm -rf umd
$ ../../node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
Done in 2.93s.
-bash: /usr/bin/webpack: No such file or directory
```

How does the npm script find that webpack binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `webpack` binary is installed in `./node_modules/.bin/` relative to that package.json. npm scripts run with that directory on their PATH, see: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path